# Canvas Polygon Function Fills At Wrong Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I wrote my own polygon function; the problem is when I want to have the polygon only draw a border, it ends up using the previous fillStyle and draws over previous polygons.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const HP_DARKGREEN = '#003100'
const HP_LIGHTGREEN = '#007E00'
var health = 50

function polygon(x1, y1, border = {
  color: 'black',
  width: 1,
  lineJoin: 'round',
  lineCap: 'square'
}, fillColor = false, ...coords) {
  /* Draws a polygon given an array of coordinates */
  let c = coords
  ctx.translate(x1, y1)
  if (border) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = border.color
  }
  ctx.beginPath()
  for (let i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i += 2) {
    ctx.lineTo(c[i], c[i + 1])
  }
  ctx.closePath()
  if (fillColor) {
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
    ctx.fill()
  }
  if (border) {
    ctx.lineWidth = border.width
    ctx.lineCap = border.lineCap
    ctx.lineJoin = border.lineJoin
    ctx.stroke()
  }
  ctx.translate(-x1, -y1)
}

//Trying to draw these polygons
polygon(14, 4, false, HP_DARKGREEN, 114, 4, 104, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)

polygon(14, 4, false, HP_LIGHTGREEN, health + 14, 4, health + 4, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)

polygon(14, 4, {
  color: 'black',
  width: 2
}, false, 114, 4, 104, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)

var Render = {
  clear: () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  },
  update: () => {
    Render.clear()
    Render.display.health()
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      Render.update()
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=192 height=192></canvas>
```

Now that I look at it, it seems to work beautifully in JSFiddle. The only difference is that in the actual program, I use `requestAnimationFrame()` to loop through the rendering process. The problem is being caused by the third polygon (it fills the entire bar with the lightgreen color).

Edit: I just tried to run the function just once in my code. It worked fine; when I ran the loop function, it failed to draw correctly. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the default parameters or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is exactly what you would expect. An unfinished line of code completely unrelated to this was causing all of the problems. Programming is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const HP_DARKGREEN = '#003100'
const HP_LIGHTGREEN = '#007E00'
var health = 50

function polygon(x1, y1, border = { color: 'black', width: 1, lineJoin: 'round', lineCap: 'square'}, fillColor = false, ...coords) {
   /* Draws a polygon given an array of coordinates */
   let c = coords
   ctx.translate(x1, y1)
   if (border) { ctx.strokeStyle = border.color }
   ctx.beginPath()
   for (let i=0; i<c.length - 1; i+=2) {
    ctx.lineTo(c[i],c[i+1])
   }
   ctx.closePath()
   if (fillColor) {
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
    ctx.fill()
   }
   if (border) { 
    ctx.lineWidth = border.width
    ctx.lineCap = border.lineCap
    ctx.lineJoin = border.lineJoin
    ctx.stroke()
   }
   ctx.translate(-x1, -y1)
  }
    
//Trying to draw these polygons
function drawPoly(){
 polygon(14, 4, false, HP_DARKGREEN, 114, 4, 104, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)
 polygon(14, 4, false, HP_LIGHTGREEN, health + 14, 4, health + 4, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)
 polygon(14, 4, { color: 'red', width: 2 }, false, 114, 4, 104, 19, 4, 19, 14, 4)
  health--;
  if(health<0){
    health = 0;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawPoly);
}
drawPoly();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=192 height=192></canvas>
```

Comment: No, that I can accomplish pretty easily. The issue i'm having is that the third polygon (the one with the red border in your case) makes the entire bar light green. This doesn't happen on JSFiddle. I'm going to try to add more code to replicate this problem.